# knockoutjs "Unable to parse bindings" error, but code works

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been using knockout for a while, but in writing up some code examples this one has me stumped. The code works exactly as I'm expecting, where the click button toggles the visible, but I'm still getting an error:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/hCdF8/1/

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: answerClick is not defined;
Bindings value: click: answerClick
```

from

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: answers">
    <li>
        <a class="hiddenButton" href="#" data-bind="click: answerClick" />
        <div class="answerNumber" data-bind="visible: showAnswerNumber">
            <h2 data-bind="text: answerNumber" />
        </div>
        <div class="answer" data-bind="visible: showAnswerText">
            <p data-bind="text:text" />
            <p data-bind="text: points" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var answerViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        //clicks
        self.answerClick = function () {
            self.showAnswerNumber(!self.showAnswerNumber());
        };

        //observables
        self.answerNumber = ko.observable();
        self.text = ko.observable();
        self.points = ko.observable();
        self.showAnswerNumber = ko.observable(true);

        //computed
        self.showAnswerText = ko.computed(function () {
            return !self.showAnswerNumber();
        });
    };

    var roundViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.answers = ko.observableArray();
    };

    var answer1 = new answerViewModel();
    answer1.text = "foo answer";
    answer1.answerNumber = 1;
    answer1.points = 50;

    var vm = new roundViewModel();
    vm.answers.push(answer1);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are closing your anchor tag:  `<a />`, it is getting rendered in a strange way where an extra anchor tag is outside of the `foreach` and not in a context where `answerClick` is a valid function.

I am not sure what content that you want to use for your link, but you need to have an opening and closing tag like:

`<a class="hiddenButton" href="#" data-bind="click: answerClick">link</a>`

Not sure if you intended to wrap the content in that link, but that is where your issue lies.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hCdF8/2/

Comment: Thanks man! Duh moment for me. I was taking an existing app that uses 1/2 of a div as the click area, and css to fill the <a> link with. When I made the code above, I was being dumb :-)

Comment: I spent an hour on a similar bug last night.  Hard to see it sometimes.

Comment: I've found out that sometimes when I am binding something inside of a "with:" I've got the same error despite the code works. If I remove the "with:" clause and add the whole path from $root, the error goes.